# How to teach neural network a policy for a board game using reinforcement learning?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I need to use reinforcement learning to teach a neural net a policy for a board game. I chose Q-learining as the specific alghoritm.

I'd like a neural net to have the following structure:

1. layer - `rows * cols + 1` neurons - input - values of consecutive fields on the board (`0` for empty, `1` or `2` representing a player), action (natural number) in that state
2. layer - (??) neurons - hidden
3. layer - 1 neuron - output - value of action in given state (float)

My first idea was to begin with creating a map of states, actions and values, and then try to teach neural network. If the teaching process would not succeed I could increase the number of neurons and start over.

However, [I quickly ran into performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597386/how-to-improve-performance-of-a-script-operating-on-large-amount-of-data). Firstly, I needed to switch from simple in-memory Python `dict` to a database (not enough RAM). Now the database seems to be a bottleneck (simply speaking there are so many possible states that the retrieval of actions' values is taking a noticeable amount of time). Calculations would take weeks.

**I guess it would be possible to teach neural network on the fly, without the layer of a map in the middle. But how would I choose a right number of neurons on the hidden layer? How could I figure out that I'm loosing periously saved (learned) data?**

Comment: I think you should post this question on game dev stack. You'll get better game related answers there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarification on a Neural Net that plays Snake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099814/clarification-on-a-neural-net-that-plays-snake)

Comment: @devinbost it's like you're trying to get every question on neural networks closed and pointed at the one question you have answered. Are they really all duplicates? I have seen at least 15 so far...

Comment: @tomredfern they are all questions that I would give the same answer to. They're questions asked by individuals who really are primarily lacking understanding of the mechanics of neural networks, and I didn't know how else to help them because I got in trouble for giving people the link to my other answer and then got in trouble for copying relevant parts into each question. I was told to instead flag them as duplicate. Now you're saying I shouldn't do that either?

Comment: @devinbost - No you shouldn't be doing that. I get that you have a stock answer which will help many people. This is a good thing, and I understand that your intentions are good also. However, flagging questions as duplicate which are clearly not duplicates is not the way to do this. Much better would be to post a comment with a link to the answer that the questioner can then follow.

Comment: @devinbost I can see how Martijn Pieters' advice was easy to misinterpret. However, he did say the following: *If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question*. This is the key. Even though your answer might be helpful, it wasn't tailored to the question. On StackOverflow, each question which is not a duplicate expresses a unique cry for help, and demands of an answerer that the answer also be unique. You should not see this as overhead. Crafting an exact answer to a specific question is what StackOverflow is built on.